# Best practices for updating a progress from background service [Android]

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, progress

Sorry If I am asking question again, but I didn't find any relevant information for this question.

I am downloading/uploading a File in background service. From this service I want to send the progress of File Downloading/Uploading. One method I know is to send broadcast on every 5% or 10% of File Downloading/Uploading. The other one is to bind the activity with service, implement an interface, and the service will notify the binded activity, that which File has been Downloaded/Uploaded. I don't know which method is good. If you have some other good method please share with me. There can be up to 5 simultaneous File Downloading/Uploading.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE:
I am not staying in the activity, where I started the downloading, user can go back to home, can start using some other app, but whenever, he comes back, he will be notified with updated progress of File Downloading/Uploading

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is use *IntentService*
The IntentService class provides a straightforward structure for running an operation on a single background thread. This allows it to handle long-running operations without affecting your user interface's responsiveness. Also, an IntentService isn't affected by most user interface lifecycle events, so it continues to run in circumstances that would shut down an AsyncTask

But an IntentService has a few limitations:

- It can't interact directly with your user interface. To put its results in the UI, you have to send them to an Activity.
- Work requests run sequentially. If an operation is running in an IntentService, and you send it another request, the request waits until the first operation is finished.
- An operation running on an IntentService can't be interrupted.

However, in most cases an IntentService is the preferred way to perform simple background operations.

**Note:** If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21), you should use JobScheduler to execute background services.